# How to get all values of an enum?

Tags: c#, enums

I want to create a method that takes in an `Enum` type, and returns all it's members in an array, How to create such a function?

Take for example, I have these two enums:

```
public enum Family
{ 
   Brother,
   Sister,
   Father
}

public enum CarType
{ 
   Volkswagen,
   Ferrari,
   BMW
}
```

How to create a function `GetEnumList` so that it returns

1. `{Family.Brother, Family.Sister, Family.Father}` for the first case.
2. `{CarType.Volkswagen, CarType.Ferrari, CarType.BMW}` for the second case.

I tried :

```
private static List<T> GetEnumList<T>()
{
    var enumList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
        .Cast<T>().ToList();
    return enumList;
}
```

But I got an `InvalidOperationException`:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true.
>           at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.ThrowNoInvokeException()
>           at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
>           at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>           at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)

**Edit: The above code is working fine-- the reason I got an exception was because profiler caused me the bug. Thank you all for your solutions.**

Comment: It worked fine for me - can you post the calling code?

Comment: Yes, it's working fine-- I found that my profiler actually cause me a bug and hence results in the exception.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Same as the other answer but updated for modern C#:

```
public static List<TEnum> GetEnumList<TEnum>() where TEnum : Enum 
    => ((TEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))).ToList();
```

Comment: "Modern" is very short-lived. .Net core 5 has `Enum.GetValues<TEnum>()`.

Answer (score 30):

Here is the full code:

```
    public enum Family
    {
        Brother,
        Sister,
        Father
    }

    public enum CarType
    {
        Volkswagen,
        Ferrari,
        BMW
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetEnumList<Family>());
        Console.WriteLine(GetEnumList<Family>().First());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static List<T> GetEnumList<T>()
    {
        T[] array = (T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
        List<T> list = new List<T>(array);
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: What is the difference between the following:
(1)Enum.GetValues (typeof (theEnum)); // returns the pure enumeration defined in Enum
(2)int i = (int) theEnum.item; // Indicator number from zero if not set and if they are set their value----
(3)Enum.GetNames (typeof (theEnum)); // Enumeration name returns as string

Answer (score 16):

```
(Family[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Family))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want a general method that takes in enum type and return the respective list-- but a specific cast function.

Answer (score 8):

Like this?

```
private static List<string> GetEnumList<T>()
{
    return Enum.GetNames( typeof( T ) )
           .Select(s => typeof(T).Name + "." + s).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since .NET 5 you can do this:

```cs
public static T[] GetAll<T>() where T : struct, Enum
{
    return Enum.GetValues<T>();
}
```